# how to do i automatically set the user field to current user in django modelform

Tags: django

How can i set the current login user to the user field of django model .In my view ,i am using function base view .My model is something like this .
Model.py

```
class DistributionProfile(Abstract_Class):
      Distributortype =(
                   ('B2B1','b2b'),
                   ('b2c','b2c'),
                   ('c2c','c2c'),
                   ('govt4','govt'), 
                 )
      ManufacturerType=(('Machine1','Machines'),
                  ('Pharmaceutical2','Pharmaceutical'),
                  ('Jewelries3','Jewelries'),
                  ('Furniture4','Funitures'),
                  ('Electronics5','Electronics'),('Textile6','Textile'),
                  ('Constructionmaterials7','ConstructionHardware'),
                  ('Beverages8','Beverages'),
                  ('Cosmetics9','Cosmetics'),
                  ('Convectionaries10','Convectionaries'),
                  ('AgriculturalProduce11','AgriculturalProduce'),
                  ('RawMaterials12','RawMaterials'),
                  ('CrudOil13','CrudOil'),
                  ('SeaFood14','SeaFood'),

                  )
    title =models.CharField(choices=Distributortype ,null=True,max_length=250,blank=False)
    ManufacturerOfInterest =MultiSelectField(choices=ManufacturerType,null=True,blank=False,max_choices=14)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
    promot=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=False) 
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    user=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

bellow is my form.I would love the form to automatically have the information of the login user  filling the form  .Meaning the user field should automatically have the information of the login in user .So that i can easily query and display objects created by the login user
form.py

```
class   DistributionProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model= DistributionProfile


         exclude=  ['slug','user','CreatedTime','verified','promot','UpdatedTime']
         widgets ={
         'CompanyRegisteredName':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'distributorform','placeholder':'Name of your company','autofocus':'True'}),
         'CompanyRegisteredState':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'distributorform','placeholder':' StateOfRegistry'}),
         'CompanyRegisteredAddress':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'distributorform','placeholder':'Company Address'}),
         'CompanyRegisteredCity':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'distributorform','placeholder':'Company registered city'}),
         'CompanyWebsiteLink':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'distributorform','placeholder':'www.mycompany.com'}),
         'RegisteredCompanyType':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'distributorform '}),
         'Country':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'distributorform'}),
         'ManufacturerOfInterest ':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'multiple_select'}),


    }
         fields=['CompanyRegisteredName',
            'CompanyRegisteredState',
            'CompanyRegisteredAddress',
            'CompanyRegisteredCity', 
            'CompanyWebsiteLink',
            'RegisteredCompanyType',
            'Country','title',
            'ManufacturerOfInterest'

            ]
```

view.py

```
def SetUpDistributor(request):
if not request.user:
    return HttpResponse('login to access this page ')
if request.method =='POST':

    distributor = DistributionProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if distributor.is_valid():
        distributor.save(commit=False)
        distributor.user=request.user
        distributor.save()
        messages.success(request,'Distributor profile created ')
        return redirect('gbiz1990:distributor_profile_setup')
    else:
        messages.error(request,'Something went wrong')
else:
    distributor=DistributionProfileForm()
return render(request,"gbiz1990/User_function_pages/distributors.html",{'distributor':distributor})
```

Answer (score 5):

Your views, may looks like that:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        your_object = form.save(commit=False)
        your_object.user = request.user
        your_object.save()
        return redirect('your_success_url')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

You need to adapt some parts, but in the general the should be your view. You need to pay attention to that this view needs a `login_required` decorator in order to not allow non-logged users to create objects.

Comment: how  can i create my object .With lots of examples i have tried none seem to work .I am very new to programming .Assume i know nothing .please

Comment: Update your question and add the entire code of your view, please. Or send a link to a gist in here.

Comment: Thanks i have edited ,and added  my full codes .If you can help me solve this problem

Comment: i am not seen anything wrong in your view, what is the error?

Comment: when i check in the admin , the user field is empty .Where by it was suppose to  be populated with the login user name who created the object .

Comment: How can i make sure in the admin ,the user field should automatically  display the name of the user who created the object .

Comment: you should use `if not request.user.is_authenticated():` on that if inside the views.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request.user`. I don't know how your app works but when creating, do this:

```
model = ModelName(user = request.user)
model.save()
```

I used `ModelName` because it is best practise to start a class name with a capital, which is not fulfilled in your `create` model. I suggest you change this.

There also seems to be a mistake in your view, it should be `request` not `reques`.

---

Your view could be like so:

```
def index(request):
    form = FormName(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, "path/to/template", {"form": form})
```

And your template could be:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo .Please show me in details how will you create your view  using a  function base view .I just want to be able to automatically get the login user to the user field of the model.

Comment: I have added an example but I don't know what your aim is or the purpose of it is.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.I have asked similar question with all my codes ,and i will love to tag you to it .will that be possible .

Comment: I am also using a django model form ,where the login user can enter in formation .

Comment: Please look in to  it .It contains my code.But yet no one has answered it .

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: i edited my question can you please have a look at it once more .

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my problem
 in my model.py

```
class SetdistributorProfile(models.Model):
      user=modelss.foreignkey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True,unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def SetDistribution(request):
    if not requested.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('app_name:url_name)
    if request.method === 'POST':
       dis = MymodelForm(request.POST or None)
       if dis.is_valid():
       instance=dis.save(commit=False)
       instance.user=request.user
       instance.save()
       return redirect('myappname:urlname')
     else:
        instance=MymodelFomr()
     context={'intance':intance}
     return render(request,'page.hmtl',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this in your views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        yourModel = YourModel(user_id = request.user.id)
        form = YourModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=yourModel)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```