# issue with setting up the username field in form initial in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form with a username field. The form is available only for logged-in users. I am trying to populate the username in the User field but with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(default='')
    title = CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    body = RichTextField(max_length=1500)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.user.username
        super(Feedback, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
captcha = ReCaptchaField()
user = forms.CharField(initial='username') # it displays username as a string but request.user.username doesn't work here
class Meta:
    model = Feedback
    fields = ['user', 'email', 'title', 'body', 'captcha']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def hal_feedback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST, initial={"username": request.user.username}) # putting request.user.username in initial also it also doesn't work
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Feedback'
            message = render_to_string('articles/post_question_confirmation.html', {
                'obj': obj,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'content': body,
                'title': title,
            })
            obj.save()
            send_mail(subject, message, "auth.ADMIN", [email], fail_silently=False)

            return redirect('success')
        else:
            initial = {'username':request.user.username}
            form = FeedbackForm(initial=initial)
    return render(request, "articles/question.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: In your `else` block it's not the same form you instantiate **(HALFeedbackForm)** instead of **(FeedbackForm)**.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to do i automatically set the user field to current user in django modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940623/how-to-do-i-automatically-set-the-user-field-to-current-user-in-django-modelform)

Comment: Is your else statement supposed to be if the request method is GET or if the `form.is_valid` returns false?